# CUDA multiple files

Tags: cuda

Is there any way to do like this in CUDA + C++??

class : 1

```
class1
{
   __device__ ....//some cuda code

    void ExecuteCuda1(); //this should execute the cuda code in this class
}
```

class : 2

```
 class2
{
   __device__ ....//some cuda code

    void ExecuteCuda2(); //this should execute the cuda code in this class
}
```

class : 3

```
class3
{
   cl1 = new class1();
   cl1->ExecuteCuda1();

   cl1 = new class2();
   cl1->ExecuteCuda2();
}
```

Comment: Yes, we have a linker now. They call the option "relocatable device code".

Answer (score 3):

No, your code won't work, because `ExecuteCuda1` and `ExecuteCuda2` are `__host__` functions, meaning they will execute on the CPU.  It's illegal for a `__host__` function to call any function marked as `__device__`, even if they are member functions of a common class.

Structuring your code like this will work:

```
__global__ kernel1() {...}

class Class1
{
  void ExecuteCuda1()
  {
    // launch kernel1
    kernel1<<<...>>>();
  }
};

__global__ kernel2() {...}

class Class2
{
  void ExecuteCuda2()
  {
    // launch kernel2
    kernel2<<<...>>>();
  }
};

class Class3
{
  void ExecuteCuda3()
  {
    Class1 cl1 = new class1();
    cl1->ExecuteCuda1();

    Class2 cl2 = new class2();
    cl2->ExecuteCuda2();
  }
};
```

Note that `__global__` function cannot be member functions, even if they are declared `static`.  That's why we must define the kernels outside of any class.  As Dan says, the code must be defined within a single translation unit, due to the absence of a CUDA linker.  You can achieve this in multiple files by using header files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but device code (i.e. functions marked with **device** or **global**) must be visible in the same compilation unit where it is needed, i.e. no linking.

So as long as you had the definitions of `Class1` and `Class2` in headers and not just the declarations then it should work.